# How do I set up the deployment section in PhpStorm?

Tags: deployment, vagrant, phpstorm, homestead

This is a two part question.

The first part is how do I fill out the deployment section of PhpStorm, if I am trying to set up Homestead via vagrant. I have attached a picture showing how I think it needs to be set up.

[image]

---

The second question is whenever I try and click the "Test Connection" button I get the error shown in the second image. How can I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it :)

Okay so I had to change several things. But in the end this is what it looks like.

[image]